# shell/awk script working fine on ubuntu/mint but not working properly on red hat

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I am new to linux and its shell programming.

I wrote a shell script on ubuntu and linux mint which is working perfectly on their systems.

Now when I tried to run this shell script on red hat , whole output is weird.

**Problem:**

1. \n characters are printed as it is , no new line is being printed.
2. some errors occuring like `expr:non-integer argument`.I have used only three types of statements for comparison -

   ```
   1.     if [ "$proto" = "TCP" ]

   2.     if [ "$prot_no" = "06" ]

   3.     if [ "$i" -eq 32 ]
   ```

I don't know where exactly is the error but there was no error on ubuntu and mint systems.

I have heard that Default shell in ubuntu is `bash` while in red hat is `ksh` but I am not sure about this.

If this is the case then how can I change my shell or if possible is there any command by which I can run my script through bash shell so that there would not be any need to make any change in the script.

Please help me .... It is almost impossible to change all `\n` characters in the script.

**Edit:**

1. for `\n` issue  this is a sample line ..

   ```
   echo "\n\n$proto Header"
   ```
2. for other errors here is some code which may possibly help ...

   ```
    if [ "$trans_or_tunn" -eq 1 ]

    then

   prot_no=`head -n 1 decrypt.txt | awk -F " " '{printf "%s",$7}'`

   if [ "$prot_no" = "06" ]
   then
           proto="TCP"

   else if [ "$prot_no" = "11" ]
        then
           proto="UDP"

        else if [ "$prot_no" =  "3a" ]
                   then
                   proto="ICMP"

              fi
         fi

      .....
   ```

   `echo "\n\n$proto Header"` this line was supposed to print one of the three values ..
   `TCP HEADER`,`UDP HEADER` or `ICMP HEADER`.

but what is actually printed out on screen is ..

**Output on screen for above line**
`\n\nHeader`

Comment: Thanx for a quick response but script is having around 1000 lines of code.. how can I do that ??? .If possible tell me any way through which I can run the same script on red hat without changing the script.

Comment: To diagnose the `\n` issue we'll need to see sample code where you attempt to print the newline. The non-integer argument is due to a variable expanding to a non-integer value or being empty; if you know which line this error occurs on that would help. The default shell doesn't matter as long as your script's bang line is correct. If you need bash specify bash.

Comment: I can only suppose that `$trans_or_tunn` does not contain an integer. I imagine it contains the string `expr`. Where's the code that assigns to it? Have you tried turning on `set -x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the first line of the script from

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Use `echo -e` to get `echo` to print `\n` as a newline.

Use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` for tests.

Explanation: the default shell on Ubuntu is `dash`, not `bash`. This is a rather limited (but therefore fast) shell, that is unfortunately not available on all Linux platforms. `bash`, not `ksh`, was the default shell on Red Hat the last time I checked, and is available almost everywhere, so portable shell scripting requires either targeting that or writing scripts to a common subset of `bash`, `dash` and `ksh`. (If you're interesting, the best portable subset is roughly that defined in the [POSIX standard shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18).)

Comment: what about when I have used `\n\n\n\n` four times . `-e` would probably print one newline.But there should be something like for if I want to print multiple new lines.

Comment: **"... -e would probably print one newline..."** probably not

Comment: @Udit Gupta: You need `-e` to turn on evaluation of escapes; and, yes, it will print multiple `\n` in a row. If you don't want to search and replace `echo` in your script you might consider `alias echo='echo -e'` at the top, though this could have undesired side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can change all \n characters like:

```
cat file | sed 's/\n/somethingelse/g' > newscript
```

If you have a problem with file transfer (through windows (winspc...etc, known line endings issue)
This might help you:

> Convert a.txt and write to e.txt.
>
> ```
>           dos2unix -n a.txt e.txt
> ```

you can invoke **bash** to make sure you're running bash (if it's installed in desired OS).

Comment: I think the OP meant `echo` prints `\n` as `\n`, instead of as a newline.

Comment: probably you're right, but I think I can leave my answer as kind of add-in to your explanation, even if it doesn't directly solves **Udit Gupta** problem.

Answer (score 0):

To enable automatic expansion of backslash-escape sequences you can add this line to your script after the interpreter line:

```
shopt -s xpg_echo
```

The 'bash' manpages offer further insight.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is more portable than `echo`, and newlines work properly:

```
printf "\n\n%s Header\n" "$proto"
```

As for `if [ "$i" -eq 32 ]`, what is in `$i`?

The error message mentions `expr` -- are you calling that program in your script?